# Logstash : Filter Error message from Logs

Tags: logstash

I am using Logstash to parse and filter the data. The input data looks something like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------
Environment File - 12/07/2018 09:31:19
------------------------------------------------------
-- File Name:  org/apache/catalina/core/ContainerBase/jboss/web/default-host/........... Path
------------------------------------------------------
Reading Environment Error File - 12/07/2018 09:31:19
------------------------------------------------------
-- File Name: org/apache/catalina/core/ContainerBase/jboss/web/default-host/.....
org/apache/catalina/core/ContainerBase/jboss/web/default-host........
.....Path.  Fri Dec  7 09:31:18 2018

Lock failed on recovery file org/apache/catalina/core/ContainerBase/jboss/web/default-host/
because the .......
....... text.

------------------------------------------------------
Reading Error  Files - 12/07/2018 09:31:19
------------------------------------------------------
```

The Error message contains multiple lines and no common pattern. How to filter Errors only from logs ?

Comment: Please try to format your sample.  Also, which parts do you want to keep vs ignore?

Comment: I have multiple line log in which the Error message is in the above format starting from -- File Name. I want to filter all the lines starting from --File name to text. The Error message can be of any number of lines. How can I filter the Error message from  the entire Log file

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for the [multiline codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html), where you can specify a pattern that delineates your messages.  logstash (or filebeat) will roll multiple lines up into one event.

Comment: Not exactly. The multiline codec require a pattern to group multiple lines into one event. The problem in my case is I dont have any common pattern between the lines to group them. Iam looking for a way where it can understand to start from a keyword and end at a keyword.

Comment: The multiline codec pattern lets you define what starts or ends a message.  See the examples in the doc about java stacktraces, etc.